# Functional equation of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, functional-equations

> If $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ satisfies $f(f(x))=\left(x\overline x-x-\overline x\right)^2$ and $f(1)=0$, find $f(\mathrm i)$.

If $f(a+b\mathrm i)=a^\prime+b^\prime\mathrm i$, define $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $g((a,b))=\left(a^\prime,b^\prime\right)$. Since
\[\left[(a+b\mathrm i)\overline{(a+b\mathrm i)}-a-b\mathrm i-\overline{(a+b\mathrm i)}\right]^2=\left(a^2-2a+b^2\right)^2,\]
we have $g(g((a,b)))=\left(\left(a^2-2a+b^2\right)^2,0\right)$. I don't know what to do then?

By the way, I found that $g((a,b))=\left((a-1)^2+b^2,0\right)$ satisfies.

Comment: 1/ The relation can be written as $\,f\left(f(x)\right) = \left||x-1|^2 - 1\right|^2\,$, which has $\,f(x) = |x-1|^2\,$ as a solution. If it can be proved that $\,f(i)\,$ is uniquely determined, then it must be $\,f(i) = |i-1|^2 = 2\,$.

Comment: 2/ Let $\,f(i) = t\,$, then:
$$
f(t) = f\left(f(i)\right) = \left||i-1|^2 - 1\right|^2 = 1
\\ 0 = f(1) = f\left(f(t)\right) = \left||t-1|^2 - 1\right|^2 \;\;\implies\;\; |t-1| = 1
$$

Comment: @dxiv Could you post this as an answer so I can end the question?

Comment: Those are just hints, not an answer. The first one says that $f(i)$ *could* be $2$, the second one says that $f(i)$ *must* be on the circle $|t-1|=1$. But neither one answers the question of what the value set of $f(i)$ actually is.